# How to adapt height of a div in dash (python)?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I use below app and want to adapt the height of the div with id = "change-height". To do so I add the "height" parameter in the style-parameter.

```
div_g = html.Div([g_scatter]
    , id = "change-height"
    , style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'height': '200%'}
    )
```

But the height value has no effect. But if I change the width parameter, it has en effect. How can I adapt the height of the div **div_g**? Can I set the the height the same value as the height of div **div_xy**?

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv('https://plotly.github.io/datasets/country_indicators.csv')

dd_1 = dcc.Dropdown(
                df['Indicator Name'].unique(),
                'Fertility rate, total (births per woman)',
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-column',
            )
dd_2 = dcc.Dropdown(
                df['Indicator Name'].unique(),
                'Life expectancy at birth, total (years)',
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-column'
            )
ri_1 = dcc.RadioItems(
                ['Linear', 'Log'],
                'Linear',
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-type',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block', 'marginTop': '5px'}
            )
ri_2 = dcc.RadioItems(
                ['Linear', 'Log'],
                'Linear',
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-type',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block', 'marginTop': '5px'}
            )

gx = dcc.Graph(id='x-time-series')
gy = dcc.Graph(id='y-time-series')

div_dd = html.Div([dd_1, dd_2])

sl = dcc.Slider(
        df['Year'].min(),
        df['Year'].max(),
        step=None,
        id='crossfilter-year--slider',
        value=df['Year'].max(),
        marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['Year'].unique()}
    )

div_xy = html.Div([ri_1,gx,ri_2,gy,sl]
, style={'display': 'inline-block','width': '49%'})

g_scatter = dcc.Graph(
            id='crossfilter-indicator-scatter',
            hoverData={'points': [{'customdata': 'Japan'}]}
        )

div_g = html.Div([g_scatter]
    , id = "change-height"
    , style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'height': '200%'}
    )

div_main = html.Div(
    [div_xy,div_g]
    ,style={"display": "flex"}
    )

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
      div_dd
    , div_main
    ]
    )


@app.callback(
    Output('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-year--slider', 'value'))
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name,
                 xaxis_type, yaxis_type,
                 year_value):
    dff = df[df['Year'] == year_value]

    fig = px.scatter(x=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            y=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            hover_name=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name']
            )

    fig.update_traces(customdata=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'])

    fig.update_xaxes(title=xaxis_column_name, type='linear' if xaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')

    fig.update_yaxes(title=yaxis_column_name, type='linear' if yaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')

    fig.update_layout(margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0}, hovermode='closest')

    return fig


def create_time_series(dff, axis_type, title):

    fig = px.scatter(dff, x='Year', y='Value')

    fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers')

    fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)

    fig.update_yaxes(type='linear' if axis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')

    fig.add_annotation(x=0, y=0.85, xanchor='left', yanchor='bottom',
                       xref='paper', yref='paper', showarrow=False, align='left',
                       text=title)

    fig.update_layout(height=225, margin={'l': 20, 'b': 30, 'r': 10, 't': 10})

    return fig


@app.callback(
    Output('x-time-series', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'hoverData'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value'))
def update_y_timeseries(hoverData, xaxis_column_name, axis_type):
    country_name = hoverData['points'][0]['customdata']
    dff = df[df['Country Name'] == country_name]
    dff = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]
    title = '<b>{}</b><br>{}'.format(country_name, xaxis_column_name)
    return create_time_series(dff, axis_type, title)


@app.callback(
    Output('y-time-series', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'hoverData'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value'))
def update_x_timeseries(hoverData, yaxis_column_name, axis_type):
    dff = df[df['Country Name'] == hoverData['points'][0]['customdata']]
    dff = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]
    return create_time_series(dff, axis_type, yaxis_column_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Coud you try `'height': '200'` instead of `'height': '200%'`.

Comment: @hoatran also no effect

Comment: So what do you want to get? You want height of scatter plot div same with two line plot?

Comment: Maybe example in this doc can help you: ```https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing?_gl=1*da79nm*_ga*MTM0MTQ3MDU2My4xNjU0MjQwMTM1*_ga_6G7EE0JNSC*MTY3MzQzMDc0Ny40MTcuMS4xNjczNDMzNDEwLjAuMC4w```

Comment: @hoatran I want to change height of div div_g

Comment: Maybe you can change height of graph like below:
`fig.update_layout(height=1000,margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0}, hovermode='closest')` and it will change height of Div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the height in pixels.

```py
div_g = html.Div(
    [g_scatter], 
    id = "change-height", 
    style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'height': '200px'}
)
```

If you're going to use a percentage value for the height then your div needs to be inside another div with a specific height and the parent can't have `display=flex` or the percentage won't work. See [w3 display](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.php) and [w3 position](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.php).

If you really want to use a percentage then you can set `position=absolute` in the style of `div_g` but then you'll also have to specify the top/left position.

See [w3 height property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_dim_height_percent) for reference

### Edit

By doing what I stated above the specified `div` *is* changing in height but you can't tell because the figure inside the `div` remains fixed. If you want the figure height to change you must do that via `fig.update_layout` in your callback for the figure.

```py
fig.update_layout(height=200, margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0}, hovermode='closest')
```

Comment: This solution has also does not work for me (tested on edge and firefox). It has no effect on the height. There is no difference whether I use ", 'height': '20px'" or , 'height': '2000px'.

Comment: Oh I see why. The div_g actually is changing but you can't tell because the figure height remains the same. If you want the figure height to change then do that via update_layout for your `crossfilter-indicator-scatter` figure.